# ORDER BY 2 fields

Tags: sql

Is it possible to ORDER BY 2 fields? 
EG. ORDER BY CREATED_DATE AND UPDATED_DATE

This is so that results get ORDERED BY created_date when there is a new record and also by update_date when an existing record gets updated.

Thanks

Comment: You can order by two columns so if order on one is ambiguous they will be sorted by the other. But that doesn't look like it'll fit what you want... could you provide an example result set, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

If what you mean is "order by UPDATED_DATE if it exists and by CREATED_DATE otherwise", you can use a dedicated function depending on the underlying database. For many DBMSs, it's coalesce(), and in your case:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(UPDATED_DATE, CREATED_DATE)
```

Comment: This is what I was going to answer, also try ISNULL, IFNULL,NVL if coalesce isn't implemented in your DBMS.

Comment: Thanks all. I use MYSQL/PHP platform.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you simply separate the columns you want to order by by a comma

```
ORDER BY created_date,update_date
```

Which reads as "order by created_date then by update_date". If that's not what you need, please provide furhter explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Pls is this valid? if yes what is the outcome?--------ORDER BY D.dat_updateddate DESC, D.dat_createddate DESC

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE
```

"Multiple sort columns can be specified. The sequence of the sort columns in the ORDER BY clause defines the organization of the sorted result set." From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)